# Can not load SlpClient because of dll exception C# SLP

Tags: c#, dll, slp

I try to use the slp-sharp.dll and have the following code:

```
var slp = new SlpClient(String.Empty);
Console.WriteLine("SLP Opened");

slp.Find("inbtest:inb.http", new string[0],
  delegate (string url, UInt16 lifetime)
  {
  // found a service
  Console.WriteLine("found {0}, lifetime = {1}", url, lifetime);
  });
Console.WriteLine("SLP Closed");
```

I always get an exception in the following line:

```
var slp = new SlpClient(String.Empty);
```

The DLL "slp": The specified module was not found. (Exception of HRESULT: 0x8007007E) cannot be loaded.

The slp-sharp.dll is already in the build folder and as referance set too.

Anyone with experience with slp-sharp.dll?

Comment: How do you add the reference? NuGet, the GAC, browsing to a DLL? The latter is usually a brittle solution. The `FusLogVw` tool will likely tell you what's going on

Comment: @Flydog57 Checked it with the fuslogvw. First I saw that there was a missmatch in the version. I have fixed this error. But now it comes exactly the same exception. But according to fuslogvw there are no errors at all. "The binding was successful."

Comment: So, at runtime, FusLogVw is saying "Binding was successful", but you're getting that exception.  Weird.  You can try SysInternals' "Process Monitor".  It's a lot noisier than FusLogVw, but you might see something